# Безопасен ли подготовленный запрос mysqli в таком виде?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Будет ли безопасен запрос mysqli такого вида? Где не все значения подготавливаются.

```
$stmt = Work::$sql->prepare("INSERT INTO auk (type,split,id_type,id_bet,count,autobuy,time_start,time_end,min_bet,now_bet,user,user_bet,text) VALUES ('item',0,?,0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,0,?) "); 
                                        $stmt->bind_param("iiiiiiiis", intval($item['item_id']), intval($count), intval($autobuy), intval(time()), intval($time), intval($min), intval($now), intval($userInfo['id']), $textLot);
                                        $stmt->execute();
                                        $stmt->close();
```

Увы не нашел информации конкретно по этому поводу, все, что я нашел говорит конкретно о переменных. Либо все же нужно подготавливать каждое значение, вынося его в отдельную переменную?

Comment: Гляньте тут, вроде исчерпывающая инфа: https://htmlacademy.ru/tutorial/php/sql-injections

Comment: @Borislav увы не исчерпывающий. В моем случае сперва отправляется запрос, где есть 4 перманентных значения, которые никак не меняются, и соответственно к ним не может априори(в моем понимании) иметь доступ злоумышленник. и после уже соответственно отправляются подготовленные переменные, отдельно от самого тела запроса и не могут влиять на него.
Все, что я прочитал, гласит о том, что "Будь хоть одна переменная в запросе, следует использовать подготовленное выражение". Но конкретно о том, что нужно использовать подготовленные переменные для неизменных значений, как и опровержения этому, нет.

Comment: Подготавливать вам нужно только динамические значения, т.е. те, за которые вы 100% не можете быть уверены, т.е. из request вы что-то забрали, слабо провалидировали, сунули в запрос, вот вам уязвимость. Если вы что-то хардкодите, то это прям железобетонно, это же не переменная, а истинное значение в коде. Можете не волноваться, запрос у вас нормальный.